# How can I install the Vim-CSS-Color Plugin on Mac OS X?

Tags: vim

I'm running Mac OS Lion using the built-in version of Vim (7.3) via the terminal.

I am attempting to install the [Vim-CSS-Plugin](https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color).  I have Pathogen installed and working but when I cloned the repository to my bundle directory it didn't work.  I then move the after/syntax directory to `.vim/after/syntax` as per the plugin's help page but that didn't work, either.

How can I get this plugin working on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the following variable in .vimrc made it work inside terminal also.

```
set t_Co=256
```

Reference: https://github.com/skammer/vim-css-color/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't get it working with the built-in Terminal, it works on [Macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) just fine.

Answer (score 0):

in your vimrc, do have:

`set nocompatible`

&

`filetype plugin indent on`

&

`call pathogen#infect('~/.vim/bundle')`

set?

Comment: Yes, I have all of those.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.